# Retrieve Cookies values in all pages inner website

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I use a cookies values into a project to check the visitors entered, firstly, a submit post form exist to enter an email address, after submit, the cookies is set (for next navigation to the current page, should be enter direct to the home page not to the form page if cookies is set), everything goes right, the cookies is set properly , but after navigation to another page the data is lost and no cookies exist!!! is right that cookies should be valid in all pages navigation?? the below figure some codes...

```
if((!$_COOKIE["tickets"] && $_COOKIE["email_address"]) || (empty($_COOKIE['tickets']) && empty($_COOKIE['email_address']))){
$access_vcount=intval(getCurrentValueAccess())+1;
if(getCurrentValueAccess()==0){$query_vcounts=mysql_query("insert into visitors_counter(counter) VALUES('$access_vcount')");}
else{$query_vcounts=mysql_query("update `visitors_counter` set counter='".$access_vcount."'");}
setcookie("tickets", "accessible", time()+86400);
setcookie("email_address", $email_address, time()+86400);
}
header("Location:".BURL."/".getflink(2,'en'));
```

The cookies are valid for a one day (should be that).
When i try to print the values is cookies in another page , then no result.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Is BURL the same (sub-)domain as the page, which sets the cookies?

Comment: BURL=the basic url , in my case is :http://localhost/projectname/html and the page that when the cookies are set is : BURL/pages/submit.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting a cookie on a page that redirects, the cookie must be set after the call to header('Location: ....');

Such as:

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); 
  setcookie('asite', $site, time()+60*60, '/', 'site.com');  ?>
```

---

Pasted from comments at http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: And? Did it worked? If yes, it would be nice to complete the question.

Comment: Mark the answer as corrent *cough* ;)

Comment: On the left side of answers, is this counter with arrows up and down. Directly below is a white check. If you click it, it becomes green and this marks the anweser as correct.

Comment: You should always accept answers if they are solving your question or problem, the guy how helped you earns some points for that and this is what Stackoverflow makes fun to work with.

Answer (score 0):

In the syntax

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

The path must be set correctly, as the cookie will be valid only for those paths and directories under that.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php),

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If
>   set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If
>   set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/
>   directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The
>   default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set
>   in.

Comment: i update the code to the below: setcookie("tickets", "accessible", time()+86400, '/', BURL); probably it's not affective

Comment: On which page are you calling the `setcookie()` function? What is the path of that page?

Comment: I think the path must not be set! It is optional and if it is empty, the cookie belongs to all paths.

Comment: setcookie("tickets", "accessible", time()+86400, '/', $acces_valid_coockies); with BURL=the base url site(http://localhost/projectname/html) and the page that's cookies set is: BURL/pages/submit.php